# Rich UI Web application development

Tags: javascript, angular, gwt, web-applications, html-editor

We have been developing the html template editor which allows you to drag and drop the components (TextBox,Label,Image, Videos etc), positioning and styling them. Writing boilerplate JavaScript would require huge effort, we initially thought of taking advantage of GWT. Since GWT is Java based, I wonder if any JavaScript libraries are available as an alternative to it.
 I went though the typescript and angular2 but not very sure whether such sophisticated application can be developed using it. I would be very happy to know if someone helps to compare the power of GWT and angular2 or any other libraries available for my requirement. Thank you.